# ubuntu Vs. www-data File permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ftp, sftp

I always having problem in setting file permission and group ownership. Some time I will manage to edit files through SFTP some times not And same from web server.

So let me clear what I do usually

```
1- Create an AWS Instance (Ubuntu 18.04)
2- Installed Apache/PHP 7.2/MySQL and other PHP Modules
3- It creates a web server directory on /var/www/html
4- I put my files here.
```

Initially it was owned by root so I change it `ubuntu` user, as I am logged in into SFTP through `ubuntu` user and PPK file through `WinScp` FTP client. So I am able to upload files through `SFTP` after changing the permission.

But after some time I need my web server should also have appropriate permission so if I need to install something like `WordPress` plugin then it can be installed from the admin area.

So I always have to Google everything about it and somehow I get success but it disturbs my permission that are given for FTP user `ubuntu`. I read lot of article and done so far but not able to set proper permission so both web server user `www-data` and FTP user `ubuntu` both should get proper permission so they both are illegible to add or edit files.

I need help from you guys. Can some one tell me a step by step guide to give a file permission after creating AWS instance and installing `apache` and `php`.

I have shared my current file permission. I have printed it by running command `ls -l`.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data   420 May 14 15:12 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data    19 May 14 15:12 info.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  6919 May 14 15:12 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 ubuntu www-data  4096 May 14 15:12 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data   369 May 14 15:12 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  2283 May 14 15:12 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  2898 May 14 15:12 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  4398 May 16 13:03 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 ubuntu www-data  4096 May 14 15:32 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  3847 May 14 15:12 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 19 ubuntu www-data 12288 May 14 15:12 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  2502 May 14 15:12 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  3306 May 14 15:12 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data 38883 May 14 15:12 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  8403 May 14 15:12 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data 17947 May 14 15:12 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data 31085 May 14 15:12 wp-signup.php
drwxrwxrwx  3 ubuntu www-data  4096 May 14 15:35 wp-snapshots
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  4764 May 14 15:12 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data  3068 May 14 15:12 xmlrpc.php
```

Thanks in Advance